# 'Heavy traffic' whilst creating PDFs using GS from gSheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am having trouble getting a Google Sheets script to create pdfs from the Sheets file.

The data to be printed (rows on a sheet) is identified by two parameters into a 2D array and then each element of that array placed on a preformatted sheet with lookups to fill various cells - all that works well.

The sheet is then used to create a pdf (see sample script), the pdf saved in a directory, and the sheet reset before repeating the process.

All that works well for the first 6 or so pdfs (and the pdfs are just what I want), but after the sixth (usually) the pdf saved is actually an html file with the message

> This file might be unavailable right now due to heavy traffic.

generated by Google.
This goes for two or three pdfs then a couple of good pdfs then the mock-pdfs (htmls) etc until completed.

```
    //  form checking arrays     sd (data), sp (print) are sheets in the file SSHEET
    const lastRow = sd.getLastRow();   // last row of entries
    const printList = [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []];
    const entNo = sd.getRange(2, 14, lastRow - 1).getValues().flat();
    const entCat = sd.getRange(2, catCol, lastRow - 1).getValues().flat();
    const prLabel = sd.getRange(2, 37, lastRow - 1).getValues().flat();

    // check each entry and add to array if to be printed   
    for (let i = 0; i < entNo.length; i++) {
      if (prLabel[i] !== "Printed" && (printAll || prLabel[i] == "Yes")) {
        printList[catsNames.indexOf(entCat[i])].push(entNo[i]);
      }
    }

    //set print parameters
    const printParams = objectToQueryString( {
      "size": 7, 
      "fzr": false, 
      "portrait": false,
      "fitw": false,
      "gridlines": false,
      "printtitle": false,
      "top_margin": 0.5,
      "bottom_margin": 0.5,
      "left_margin": 0.25,
      "right_margin": 0.25,
      "sheetnames": "false",
      "pagenum": "UNDEFINED",
      "attachment": false,
      "gid": sp.getSheetId(),
      "r1": 1,
      "c1": 1, 
      "r2": 25,
      "c2": 13, } );
    // Gets the folder in Drive where the PDFs are to be stored.
    const folder = getFolderByName_(OUTPUT_FOLDER_LABEL);
    const url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + SSHEET.getId() + "/export" +
    "?format=pdf&" + printParams;
    const params = { 
    'method': 'get', 
    'headers': { "authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() }, 
    'muteHttpExceptions': true, 
    'contentType': 'application/pdf' };

    //  print pdfs per category
    for (let ic = 0; ic < 9; ic++) {
      //  set up the Label sheet
      let ne = 4;
      sp.getRange(4, 15, 6, 1).clearContent();
      let prList = printList[ic].length;
      if (prList > 0) {
        for (let ie = 0; ie < prList; ie++) {
          if (ne > 9) {
            SSHEET.toast(catsNames[ic], 'Printing Labels for:', 2);
            var pdfTime = timeMark(); 
            let pdfName = catsList[ic] + "-" + sp.getRange(10, 15).getValue() + pdfTime;
            //  form the file
            const blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getBlob().setName(pdfName + '.pdf');
            //  and save it
            folder.createFile(blob);
            //  reset Label sheet
            ne = 4;
            sp.getRange(4, 15, 6, 1).clearContent();
          }                       
          sp.getRange(ne, 15).setValue(printList[ic][ie]);
          ne++;
        }
        if (ne > 4) {
          SSHEET.toast(catsNames[ic], 'Printing Labels for:', 2);
          var pdfTime = timeMark();               // creates 10-digit string
          let pdfName = catsList[ic] + "-" + sp.getRange(10, 15).getValue() + pdfTime;
          //  form the file - THIS IS WHERE THE TROUBLE LIES
          const blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getBlob().setName(pdfName + '.pdf');
          //  and save it
          folder.createFile(blob);
          //  reset Label sheet
          ne = 4;
          sp.getRange(4, 15, 6, 1).clearContent();
        }
      }
    }
    SSHEET.toast('', 'Printing Labels completed', 2);
  }
```

The problem occurs in the blob formation. The *'muteHttpExceptions'* parameter is set to true which allows the run to complete - instead of aborting the error message becomes html in the pdf output, but it does show that traffic clears enough for on, sometimes two, pdfs to be created later.
I've been testing using 98 sets of data which create 21 pdfs.

I have tried putting a delay loop in after each pdf (refer to *"How to pause App Scripts until spreadsheet finishes calculation*") to no avail; tried printing in a different order to no avail; tried forcing longer execution time by using inefficient loops to set the sheet up to no avail. Am now having to think of some way of forcing batch processing with manual intervention needed to start each batch (using 'alert' to cause breaks needing a response has no effect).

Anyone with any other ideas, or better anyone who can point out what is wrong with my script?

ADDITIONAL INFO

Putting together dummy sheets that would work with the above script would be a major task, firstly to create them - four actual sheets involved - and secondly anonymising the data (at the moment I am working with previous years data with the agreement of entrants - it is all for a student's competition - for testing purposes only by me).

The following screenshots may make things a little clearer.

1. A screenshot of the directory showing the files created
   [image]
2. What the pdf looks like
   [image: The pdf output]
3. The html output in lieu of a pdf
   [image: the error message in html]
4. The template sheet with one (of six) entries - the cells all contain 'xlookup' formulae.
   [image: template with one entry]

The script to fill the template, repeatedly, works just fine. What the problem is is the 'heavy traffic' causing an error html instead of the pdf to be created and saved.

Comment: sd is undefined

Comment: Can you share a dummy sheet for replication purposes?

Comment: Thanks Cooper and SputnikDrunk2 for your interest. I have added some more info which perhaps may help in understanding the problem - which I now think is probably not so much a script problem as a one of handling data flow.

Comment: I don't know what your data looks like, but this looks tailor-made for a merge to a Google Doc.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is exponential backoff.  There appears to be a behind the scenes pdf creation limit that I can't find documentation for.  Trial and error showed that after around 15 consecutive calls to the `/export` endpoint (of the spreadsheet url), the response would start failing with the `This file might be unavailable right now due to heavy traffic.` response.

The calls will succeed if you add expnonential backoff, and give at least 1 second between attempts.  In my testing, there would still be some failed calls, but all calls would consistently succeed before the third backoff attempt.

Where you have `const blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getBlob().setName(pdfName + '.pdf');` , replace with:

```
const blob = expBackoff( () => {
 const response = fetch(url, params)
 const responseCode = response.getResponseCode()
  if (responseCode?.toString()?.slice(0, 1) !== `2`) {
    const contentText = response.getContentText()
    console.log(`ERROR in URL fetch: ${contentText}`)
    throw contentText
  }
 return response?.getBlob()?.setName(pdfName + '.pdf')
}, 1 * 1000)
```

You will also need to add the exponential backoff function.  This will detect an error, and continue to try the call again until it succeeds or the specified number of attempts has been reached.  In this case, we are using the function's default of 5, but adding at least 1 second between calls.

```
/**
 *  Exponential Backoff
 *  @param {callBack} function - The callback function to be executed
 *  @param {sleepfor} number - The base number of milliseconds to sleep
 *  @param {maxAttempts} number - The maximum number of attempts to try the callback function
 *  @param {attempt} number - The current attempt
 *  @param {callBack} function - The callback function to be executed
 *  @return {object}
 */
function expBackoff(callBack, sleepFor = 200, maxAttempts = 5, attempt = 1) {
  if (!callBack || typeof callBack !== 'function') {
    throw 'you need to specify a function for expBackoff to execute'
  }
  try {
    return callBack()
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`backoff attempt ${attempt} error message: ${err}`)
    if (attempt >= maxAttempts) {
      console.log(`tried backing off ${attempt} times. Final error: ${err}`)
      throw err
    } else {
      Utilities.sleep(Math.pow(2, attempt) * sleepFor) +
        Math.round(Math.random() * sleepFor)
      return expBackoff(callBack, sleepFor, maxAttempts, attempt + 1)
    }
  }
}
```